# same model gives different values

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I built a MLP  for  classification problem. I used KDD99 dataset. but the problem is that when I run it it gives ech time a different value of accuracy.
Is this logic? I mean could the same model for the same data gives each time a different value of accuracy? if so why?

Comment: Depending on initialization of weights and the cost function, your model can get to different local minima, thereby giving different values of accuracy.

Comment: so how to fix it

Comment: sometimes it gives 0.99 and sometimes it gives 0.19 .

Comment: I used keras cntk. and I used categorical crossentropy

Comment: You can go to the documentation and check if you can change the initialization or not. I don't know about keras that much but in other ML models, a **random_state** option is present so that you get same results everytime for same data and model.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "run" you mean training run. Different training runs can have different performances due to many factors:

- Different random initialization.
- Different data sampling because of stochastic gradient descent (SGD).
- Stopping in different local minima.
- Stopping training before asymptotic performance.